# Is it threadsave to pass shared_pointer by const reference?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety, smart-pointers

I often read I should pass a shared_ptr by const reference to a function, because its faster. When I think about it I am not sure if this is a realy good advice, because I am not sure if this would be threadsave. Can anybody tell me if this would be threadsave to pass by const ref?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should prefer passing by `const&` to avoid the overhead of a copy of any class. For example, this is particularly important for stuff like `std::string`.

In the case of passing a `shared_ptr` by `const&` the overhead is mostly the [incrementing and decrementing of the reference count](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C-and-Beyond-2011-Scott-Andrei-and-Herb-Ask-Us-Anything#time=05m00s) because it's atomic.

**BUT! There is a gotcha when creating a thread with `const& shared_ptr`**: the reference count will be incremented. Since it is incremented, it's almost like if you had passed it by value. You are in fact passing by-value to the `std::thread` ctor, thus the increment, then passing by ref to the function.

See for yourself:

```
// gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.4
void test(const shared_ptr<int>& i)
{
  cout << "c = " << i.use_count() << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 shared_ptr<int> i(new int);
 cout << "c = " << i.use_count() << endl;
 test(i);

 cout << "thread!" << endl;
 thread t(test, i);
 t.join();
 cout << "c = " << i.use_count() << endl;
}
```

The results being:

```
c = 1
c = 1
thread!
c = 2 // <= incremented!
c = 1 // <= thread joined!
```

`shared_ptr` is a perfect candidate for thread-safety but it will not protect you from race-conditions and dead-locks.

Comment: @GeorgeAl Thx, added that precision

Answer (score 1):

With a `&` you get the object itself.

You are not increased the ref count, you just pass over the object it self. The reason people suggest to pass by `const&` is to avoid the costs of thread-safely increasing the ref count. The cost when passing as a `const&` is same cost as copying an int or a pointer, and no temporary object will be bound to the `const&` as the constructor of the `shared_ptr` is marked `explicit`.

And because you will always have at least 1 reference to the object (the object the reference is bound to from the callee function) there is no fear the object might be destroyed while you use the local reference.

Comment: What happens if the object the reference is bound to goes out of scope? Doesnt it get destroyed because the refcount will then be 0. if this would happen, i would use memory which is destroyed if I use the ref

Comment: How is the cost of passing a `const&` vs a regular `&` different? Both are just references, so no ref count changes apply.

Comment: @Exagon, how does it go out of scope? you called the function passing the local `shared_ptr`. It can't go out of scope at least until you return from that function and until the current block the `shared_ptr` is at reaches end. eg `{ std::shared_ptr<t> my_shared = make_shared<t>(...); pass_by_constref(my_shared); return 0; }`

Comment: @rozina, yes the cost should be equal. The only difference is that one does not allow modification of the bound object.

Comment: But if the function is called on another Thread the object goes out of scope or am I wrong?

Comment: @Exagon, yes but that is a special case and you have to make sure you copy the `shared_ptr` object.

Comment: @Exagon @GeorgeAI : a `shared_ptr` passed by `const&` to a thread ctor will have it's reference count incremented. Basically, it's doing a copy behind your back. See my answer below for some sample code.

Comment: @BlakBat, I just mentioned that in a comment in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Passing by const reference is thread-agnostic. Look at following simple code:

```
void foo(const std::shared_ptr<int>& x) {
    sleep(100000);
}


void bar() {
    //...
    std::shared_ptr y = ...;
    foo(y);
}
```

`y` is going to live in the bar until `foo` returns - thus making sure `shared_ptr` remains valid. If `foo()` were to create another thread and pass `x` to it, it will have to copy it - and this will increase reference counter.

Answer (score 0):

Passing by reference is always thread safe, no matter what object gets passed. And it is irrelevant if it is a reference to const or not.